# Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) problem while calling Google App script by Ajax

Tags: ajax, google-apps-script, cross-origin-read-blocking

I try to call a script published on Google App script from a .js file by Ajax.
It works very fine when I use the url directly on the browser (I get the Json answer), however I keep getting a "Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response with MIME type text/html" when the call is done from Ajax locally.

Any idea how this could be fixed ??

```
function doGet(e) {
   Logger.log('I was called finaly');

   var data = "some data";
   var result = JSON.stringify({data: data});

   return ContentService
    .createTextOutput(e.parameter.callback + "(" + result + ")")
    .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JAVASCRIPT);
 }

let callGoogleScript = (user) => {
   console.log("callGoogleScript triggered");
   var link = "https://script.google.com/macros/s/123/exec";
   var url = link + "?callback=answer&name=";
   $.ajax({
     crossDomain: true,
     url: url + encodeURIComponent(user),
     method: "GET",
     dataType: 'jsonp'
   });
}
```

Comment: Are these information useful for your situation? https://stackoverflow.com/q/62856630/7108653 https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/a72aab0242012362c46ec69031c720d5#ajax

Answer (score 0):

### There's no need to define dataType JsonP

There's a similar [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50873764) about this. Your AJAX request is trying to retrieve a JSON with Padding `dataType: 'jsonp'`.

As per the [Jquery Documentation > JSONP](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/) says `If the URL includes the string "callback=?" (or similar, as defined by the server-side API), the request is treated as JSONP instead. See the discussion of the jsonp data type in $.ajax() for more details.`

To sum up, change your **dataType** to `json`

### Reference

[jQuery.getJSON()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/)

Answer (score 0):

To use `JSONP`, you should put the url in a script tag:

```
<script src = "https://script.google.com/macros/s/123/exec?callback=answer&name="></script>
```

`callback` function in your webapp(i.e., `answer`) will then be called. The script tag can automatically be inserted into the page in jquery using [`getScript()`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/)

See [Serving JSONP in your web pages](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/content#serving_jsonp_in_web_pages). Make sure you understand all the security implications of using `JSONP`, if you're using it in a production environment.