# Google docs - access data

Tags: go, google-docs

I want to access the data from public google docs.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/12i3Lvwb_14fQES27jVP6baqqmWUXWwM7fZy-neDH3bE/edit#gid=0

The link is working.

The code I'm using:

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "log"

    "google.golang.org/api/docs/v1"
    "google.golang.org/api/option"
)

var docURL = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/12i3Lvwb_14fQES27jVP6baqqmWUXWwM7fZy-neDH3bE/edit#gid=0"

func main() {
    ctx := context.Background()

    srv, err := docs.NewService(ctx, option.WithoutAuthentication(), option.WithEndpoint(docURL))
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Unable to retrieve Docs client: %v", err)
    }

    // Prints the title of the requested doc:
    // https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/12i3Lvwb_14fQES27jVP6baqqmWUXWwM7fZy-neDH3bE/edit#gid=0
    docId := "12i3Lvwb_14fQES27jVP6baqqmWUXWwM7fZy-neDH3bE"
    doc, err := srv.Documents.Get(docId).Do()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Unable to retrieve data from document: %v", err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("The title of the doc is: %s\n", doc.Title)
}
```

It returns 404 not found. What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I saw your showing URL of `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/12i3Lvwb_14fQES27jVP6baqqmWUXWwM7fZy-neDH3bE/edit#gid=0`, it's for Google Spreadsheet which is not Google Document. So in this case, this file cannot be retrieved using Google Docs API. Please be careful about this.

When you want to retrieve the values from this publicly shared Google Spreadsheet, how about the following modification? In this case, Sheets API v4 is used. Please be careful about this.

#### Modified script:

In the current stage, Sheets API v4 cannot be used without the API key and the access token. It seems that this is the current specification. So I thought that in your script, your `srv` cannot be used for retrieving the values from the Google Spreadsheet even when that is publicly shared. I thought that your current issue might be due to this situation. In your situation, your Spreadsheet is publicly shared. So in order to retrieve the values, the API can be used as follows.

```golang
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "log"

    "google.golang.org/api/option"
    "google.golang.org/api/sheets/v4"
)

func main() {
    APIkey := "###" // Please set your API key.

    ctx := context.Background()
    srv, err := sheets.NewService(ctx, option.WithAPIKey(APIkey))
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Unable to retrieve Docs client: %v", err)
    }

    spreadsheetId := "12i3Lvwb_14fQES27jVP6baqqmWUXWwM7fZy-neDH3bE"
    res, err := srv.Spreadsheets.Get(spreadsheetId).Do()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Unable to retrieve data from document: %v", err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("The title of the doc is: %s\n", res.Properties.Title)
}
```

#### Result:

When this script is run using the valid API key, the following result is obtained.

```
The title of the doc is: test
```

#### Note:

- If your sample is the publicly sharead Google Document, unfortunately, in the current stage, Google Docs API cannot be used with the API key even when the Document is publicly shared. It seems that this is the current specification. Please be careful this. In that case, please use the access token. The sample script for this can be seen at [here](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/quickstart/go).

#### Reference:

- [Method: spreadsheets.get](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/get)

Comment: It is not possible without api key? I can past the url in the browser and modify it, even if I'm not registered. And I want to do so programmatically.

Comment: @Muhammadali Nazarov Thank you for replying. About `It is not possible without api key? I can past the url in the browser and modify it, even if I'm not registered. And I want to do so programmatically.`, when you want to modify the Spreadsheet, it is required to use the access token. In this case, API key cannot be used. This is the current specification. I deeply apologize for this. When you want to modify the Spreadsheet without using the access token and API key, it is required to use a workaround. In this case, this my answer will be useful. https://stackoverflow.com/a/62735489